# How to switch to a change-list when using perforce command line (p4)

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I opened a bunch of files using `p4 edit` in my workspace and after making some changes on each of them, I decided to put them up for review so I staged them using `p4 change` and I got a number to mark the changelist. Once I did that I am not able to see the actual changes made in the workspace. The files have gone to a version prior to my `p4 edit`.

How do I revert my workspace to a changes pointing to a change-list?

```
p4 undo -c 403767
p4 undo @403767
p4 switch @403767
p4 revert -c 403767
```

None of the above seems to work. Also when I do a `p4 opened -u <author-name>` I have a string that says `integrate change 403767 (text)` for all the files listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `integrate change 403767` indicates that these files are open for `integrate`, so these can't be the files that you opened with `p4 edit`.

Files can be opened for `integrate` by the `p4 integrate`, `p4 copy`, `p4 merge`, or `p4 undo` command.

Further, if a file is listed by `p4 opened`, its current working state is already in your workspace.  If you had opened the file for edit and neither reverted nor submitted it, `p4 opened` would say `edit change 403767` and your edits would be in your workspace.

I will hazard a guess that what you are actually trying to do is integrate changes from another branch, and you're confused because those changes do not yet appear in your workspace.  Run:

```
p4 resolve -am
p4 resolve
```

That might get things into the state you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the unshelve command did not work. I updated my question, I have a string `integrate change 403767 (text)` at the end when I do a `p4 opened`. I just get a message `Change 403767 - no file(s) to unshelve.`

Comment: Updated the answer.  The `integrate` in the `opened` output is also not consistent with your description of what you did, so I had to take another guess.  :)